# Meteor.js - mupx deploy is giving me trouble - how can I resolve this error?

Tags: meteor

I am using `mupx` to deploy a meteor app to digital ocean.  (Using a $5 droplet with 512 MB RAM).

After I deploy, `mupx` returns this error message:

```
> mupx deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

Meteor app path    : /Users/me/myapp
Using buildOptions : {}

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'My-App' (linux)
[48.59.198.247] - Uploading bundle
[48.59.198.247] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[48.59.198.247] - Sending environment variables
[48.59.198.247] - Sending environment variables: SUCCESS
[48.59.198.247] - Initializing start script
[48.59.198.247] - Initializing start script: SUCCESS
[48.59.198.247] - Invoking deployment process
[48.59.198.247] - Invoking deployment process: SUCCESS
[48.59.198.247] - Verifying deployment
[48.59.198.247] x Verifying deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    curl: (52) Empty reply from server
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data

    > fibers@1.0.5 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
    └── type-of@2.0.1

    chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
    ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
    ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
    ├── supports-color@0.2.0
    ├── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
    └── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

    source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
    └── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)

    fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
    => Starting meteor app on port:80

    => Redeploying previous version of the app

    ------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

    -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I check the logs on the server (using `mupx logs -f`) I see the following:

```
[48.59.198.247] /opt/meteord/run_app.sh: line 36:    16 Killed                  node main.js
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository     field.
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
[48.59.198.247] /opt/meteord/run_app.sh: line 36:    16 Killed                  node main.js
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
[48.59.198.247] /opt/meteord/run_app.sh: line 36:    16 Killed                  node main.js
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
[48.59.198.247] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
[48.59.198.247] /opt/meteord/run_app.sh: line 36:    16 Killed                  node main.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My app was very simple, but apparently not light-weight. My `server/main.js` looked like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    My_LineItems.find({}, {fields: {targeting: 1, id: 1}}).observeChanges({
        changed: function(_id, fields) {
            update_targeting(fields.id, fields.targeting);
        }
    });
    My_LineItems.find({}).observeChanges({
        added: function(_id, fields) {
            update_targeting(fields.id, fields.targeting);
        }
    });
    console.log('The app should be started now...');
});
```

Apparently those requests to observe those queries were so slow that they would not allow the app to start and after the 15-second or 120-second deployCheckWaitTime the app had still not properly started.

I solved the issue by changing the code above to make it like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        My_LineItems.find({}, {fields: {targeting: 1, id: 1}}).observeChanges({
            changed: function(_id, fields) {
                update_targeting(fields.id, fields.targeting);
            }
        });
        My_LineItems.find({}).observeChanges({
            added: function(_id, fields) {
                update_targeting(fields.id, fields.targeting);
            }
        });
    }, 30);
    console.log('The app should be started now...');
});
```

With this adjustment my app was able to deploy with not problem.

Basically, every time I deployed the app it had to run through the `added` method for every item in the collection, of which there were many.  My putting this into a `Meteor.setTimeout()` I was able to get `mupx` to register the app as having started correctly and then the heavy process would just run in the background so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed for me by simply increasing the 'deployCheckWaitTime' in mup.json to 120 (I assume anything reasonably higher than the default 20 would work).  Guess it just needed more time to process.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this resolved for others by using an instance with more RAM.

Comment: I bumped up to a droplet with 1 GB of RAM and had the same issue, so I tried 2 GB of RAM and still got the same issue...

Comment: How about extending deployCheckWaitTime to 120 or so?